# How can I Get all the rows of Gridview to be editable mode?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Getting all the rows of Gridview to be editable mode.

Here is Gridview Source..

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ods"
    DataKeyNames="abc" EmptyDataText="There is no entry..." AllowPaging="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtDate" Width="60" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value1") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="txtCode" Width="60" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value2") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBobLets" Width="80" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Value3") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

like I have 10 rows in gridview, I want to show all the rows in editable mode.

Thanks